# CSS3 transform rotate without overriding transform translate

Tags: css, transform

Let's say I have an element that already has a translate applied to it:

```
<div class="elem"></div>

.elem { transform: translate(50%,0); }
```

And now I want to rotate the same element using an additional class. So now the HTML and CSS looks like this:

```
<div class="elem rotate"></div>

.elem { transform: translate(50%,0); }
.rotate { transform: rotateZ(20deg); }
```

The problem occurs when the rotation is not added to the existing translate, but rather overrides and negates it.

How do I preserve the original translate without having to bloat up my code like I did below:

```
.elem { transform: translate(50%,0); }
.rotate { transform: translate(50%,0) rotateZ(20deg); }
```

Here's a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/timothyzhu/vm84vsj7/

Thanks guys.

Comment: from the above, it seems that it is clear that 'bloating' would be faster tbh

Comment: Why would you prefer HTML/class bloat over CSS bloat? Does it really make a difference? There is no default value for the transform property, so you have to be verbose about what you want to transform or end up overwriting the declaration.

Comment: Well this sucks. I was hoping to use a series of classes that do various translations, and combining them with another series of classes that do various rotations. But because of the overriding effect, I guess I'd have to do some hackery to get it to work.

Answer (score 3):

Setting a `transform` property on an element will override any other `transform` property set previously on the same element.

One common pattern in this situation is use JS to store the value and then apply transformation  taking into account the previous transform property(also because the sequence of transformations is important!!).

In your scenario, a workaround could be creating a wrapping div just for rotation ([here's a complicated example](http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/transforms/#playground) look at it with dev-tools),

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/maio/vm84vsj7/3/)

Comment: Your workaround works. I was hoping to keep my HTML clean though.

Comment: that I know of there is no clean way

Comment: fiddle 404'd on me